# Clear rubber hose purpose for pressure washer

Tags: hose

I'm sorry if this is obvious to you guys but I'm really stumped. I recently purchased a [Black & Decker PW1470TD](http://www.lazada.com.ph/black-and-decker-pw1470td-1400w-compact-pressure-washer-orange-531505.html?boost=1)

It came with a short clear rubber hose and I can't figure out what it is for. I couldn't find it in the [manual](http://www.2helpu.com/PDMSDocuments/EU/Docs/DocPdf/PW1470TD_B1.pdf) either.

[image: Clear rubber hose thingy]

I would appreciate it if anyone could tell me. Thank you guys.

Comment: Was it just in the box, or was it attached to something? This looks like the kind of tubing that might cover something tube-like that could be damaged in transit.

Comment: It was in the plastic bag along with the filter and other small parts so it couldnt be attached to anything. It looks like a spare if you ask me.

Comment: It looks like something that might go into a bottle of soap.  Is there a place to attach something to the bottom of the nozzle or handle?

Comment: Yep, apparently it was for the nozzle of the detergent holder! Thanks @KevinKrumwiede you can answer the question and I'll mark it best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've figured out, it's the suction tube for the detergent bottle.